# SQL make internal relation between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i need to make a relation between tblPersoneel and tblWoonplaats but it is not working.

This is the code i am using

```
ALTER TABLE tblPersoneel
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Perwoon FOREIGN KEY

    REFERENCES 

        tblWoonplaats

GO
```

Comment: When you say "not working" are you getting some sort of error, or you saw that the contraint is not answering properly (which would be rather wierd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tblPersoneel ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_Perwoon FOREIGN KEY (woonplaatsId)  
REFERENCES tblWoonplaats (id)
```

Of course you need to use the correct column names for the ids.

Comment: Thanks, now i need to get the names of people from 'Waalwijk' but it is not working USE [ia_ae_ie]
SELECT voorletters, T_V, A_naam FROM tblPersoneel WHERE Woonplaats = 'Waalwijk' FROM tblWoonplaats

GO

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as correct. For your other issue, I guess you will have to use `select * from tblPersoneel p inner join tblWoonplats w on p.woonplaatsId = w.id`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the columns:

```
FOREIGN KEY (<woonplaatsID within tblPersoneel>) REFERENCES tblWoonplaats (<woonplaatsID within tblWoonplaats>)
```